# Index remains modified after git reset HEAD + git checkout

Tags: git

I tried the following steps and was surprised by the outcome:

1. copy/paste my .git/index file to a different location in order to monitor its evolution in a difftool (WinMerge)
   -> at this stage both index files are identical
2. commit a change to a single file
   -> at this stage index files are different
3. git reset HEAD^
4. git checkout .
   -> at this stage git diff shows no difference but still the index files remains different

I am just curious about how git works internally and would like to understand why the index file is modified in such a scenario.

Comment: Your 3rd step has no effect, you probably meant `HEAD~1`

Comment: You might also want to hexdump the index rather than just diff on the binary file itself, and refer to the following index format: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt

Comment: Indeed I meant HEAD^

Comment: You're both right!  `HEAD^` is equivalent to `HEAD~1`.  https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html

Comment: @EdwardThomson yep, but original was neither `HEAD~1` nor `HEAD^`, but `HEAD`, which is not the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case index could be different because of ctime and mtime that each file entry has:

[Git  index format description](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt)

If you want to compare those two you can gin and vimdiff the output for the both indices:

[gin project](https://github.com/sbp/gin)